# How to identify similar values per group in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to identify those similar values. By "similar" I mean like those in the rows (3, 5), (6, 7), and (9, 10).

"similarity" for values >= 0

90.95666667 and 90.9566666666667 are similar because both have 90 in the integer part and 95 in the decimal part (defining precision until 2 decimal numbers - > 90.96 = 90.96).

"similarity" for values < 0

0.04 and 0.045 are similar because both have "0.04" a the beginning; the same with 0.000565 and 0.00056, both have "0.00056" at the beginning.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"),
  value = c(0.05, 0.1, 90.95666667, 8, 90.9566666666667, 0.04, 0.045, 0.2, 97.95666667,     
            97.9566666666667, 109.57)
) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number())

desired result:

# A tibble: 11 × 4
   group   value   row similar_row
   <chr>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1 a       0.05      1      NA
 2 a       0.1       2      NA
 3 b      91.0       3       5
 4 b       8         4      NA
 5 b      91.0       5       3
 6 c       0.04      6       7
 7 c       0.045     7       6
 8 c       0.2       8      NA
 9 d      98.0       9      10
10 d      98.0      10       9
11 d     110.       11      NA
```

is there a way to identify those "similar" values in order to delete them in the future?.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to define similarity based on the first few significant digits.  It's not quite clear how many significant digits you want to consider because you are inconsistent in your answer.  You can use the `signif` function to round to your desired number of digits.  Then group by that value.

```
df %>% 
    mutate(significant_position = ceiling(log10(value)),
           signif = signif(value, 2)) %>% 
    group_by(group, signif) %>% 
    mutate(sim_group = cur_group_id()) %>% 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 11 × 6
   group   value   row significant_position  signif sim_group
   <chr>   <dbl> <int>                <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>
 1 a       0.05      1                   -1   0.05          1
 2 a       0.1       2                   -1   0.1           2
 3 b      91.0       3                    2  91             4
 4 b       8         4                    1   8             3
 5 b      91.0       5                    2  91             4
 6 c       0.04      6                   -1   0.04          5
 7 c       0.045     7                   -1   0.045         6
 8 c       0.2       8                    0   0.2           7
 9 d      98.0       9                    2  98             8
10 d      98.0      10                    2  98             8
11 d     110.       11                    3 110             9
```

I added the `significant_position` column to indicate where the most significant digit is.  It seems like this might play a role in your choice of parameter for the `signif` function.